Does "apprised in" have a meaning distinct from "apprised of"
Orders in some U.S.  courts often have an introductory clause that includes the phrase "the Court being fully apprised in the premises." Example:

This cause coming to be heard on Plaintiff's Motion for a Temporary
Restraining Order, counsel for both parties being present, and the
Court being fully apprised in the premises, it is ORDERED: ...

In my experience outside of the legal context, "apprised" is always followed by "of" rather than "in." And the dictionaries I've consulted also use "apprised of" in their usage examples. ("Premises" in this phrase means the statements or propositions that are the basis for the motion.)
Is there a justification / explanation for this usage, or is this an instance of someone in the distant past making a mistake, which was then slavishly copied by generations of lawyers?

Yes, slavishly copied by generations is rich, but in/of are close in meaning.

Historically there is often a lot of variation in which prepositions are used with a verb, and the thing you consider a stupid mistake might have been standard 200 years ago (a lot of legal terminology is very old; some in English law seems to date to shortly after the Norman Conquest). You could look apprise up in the OED and see how its use has varied through time, or research it on Google Books and NGrams.

Can you please say where you found that example?
My fear is that without references, it seems meaningless…

The meaning is the same and the choice of "in" v. "of" really has no deeper meaning. It is a matter of local custom and personal habit.
Both are found in Google Ngrams, and "apprised of" is more common than "apprised in", but I wouldn't call either form incorrect. Both are relatively old fashioned styles of legal writing.

I don't remember ever hearing "apprised in" used as a phrase, and a Google search of it, in quotes, comes up mostly with things like 'use apprised in a sentence' (and comes up with this very page).
It appears that "apprised in" has no specific meaning at all.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Dear Bot:
I have cited the Google search results within my answer, but I am unable to find outside documentation of my own experience. Please accept, instead, that I am documenting it here.
;)

OED to apprise:

1.a. To impart knowledge or information to; give formal notice to; inform, acquaint.


"the Court being fully apprised in the premises."

This is archaic and "legal-speak".

1694 Though the King of England may be never so well apprized in the use of them.
Lord Delamere, Works 41

Here "in" = in the matter/subject of X -> the apprising occurs within the limits of the matter/subject.

"the Court being fully apprised of the premises."

Here "of" approximates to "from" and indicates a weakened sense of the contextual origins of the apprising.

During his first day on the stand, Cohen testified that Trump was fully apprised of the payment to Daniels and promised to reimburse him. —Molly Crane-Newman, New York Daily News, 14 May 2024


I have never heard of anyone using "apprised in".  And as mentioned in another answer, Google doesn't find anything either.  However this is a valid sentence.
The team leader kept everyone apprised in real-time of any changes to the project timeline
